# Autoanimate on start - jquery scrolling carousel

Tags: jquery, scroll

Does anyone could help me to implement autoanimate scroll on start wiht jquery scrolling carousel?
Link to Scrolling Carousel:
http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/

Effect that I want (its flash):
locabarra.com.br

Answer (score 0):

Is possible, but you downloaded a Carousel so you need to find where is the code that move it. It's onMouseEnter that start and you need to put all the code inside this "event" in:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //CODE THAT MOVE THE CAROUSEL 
});
```

Than you can specify onMouseEnter to stop it..